# Subversion - svnadmin dump remote url

Tags: backup, svn, version-control, dump

I have Subversion repository that contains multiple projects, and now I'm trying to separate each project into it's own repository.

system:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11 (Tikanga)
# rpm -q subversion
subversion-1.6.11-12.el5_10
#
```

subversion:

```
$ svnadmin dump http://svn/repo1/proj1/
svnadmin: E205000: 'http://svn/repo1/proj1/' is a URL when it should be a local path
$
```

according to following document - [svnadmin—Subversion Repository Administration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svnadmin.html)

> Since svnadmin works via direct repository access (and thus can only
>   be used on the machine that holds the repository), it refers to the
>   repository with a path, not a URL.

that explains why it didn't work for me. What other alternatives ways to accomplish that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess one of the better solution would be to upgrade to Subversion version 1.7+

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.0 (Maipo)
# rpm -q subversion
subversion-1.7.14-6.el7.x86_64
#
```

As Subversion 1.7+, has following:

```
svnrdump - Subversion remote repository dumper and loader
```

And then one can use following:

```
$ svnrdump dump http://svn/repo1/proj1/ > svn.repo1.proj1
```